# SAS - compare two variables in two datsets

Tags: variables, compare, sas

I have two datasets of patients and am trying to make one data;
my first data in inpatient admissions, and second is outpatient visits. I want to compare both data sets to see if outpatient visits data have a patient then I want to add a new variable to inpatient data let's say OP_var and label it as "Yes" and if an inpatient data patient is not present in outpatient data then i want to label OP_var as "No".

e.g.`

```
data inpatient;
input PID adm_dt dis_dt hsp_id @@;
cards;
1 01/01/2013 01/03/2013 10001
2 01/03/2013 01/04/2013 10110
3 01/10/2012 01/12/2012 10010
4 01/11/2013 01/17/2013 10000
;;

data outpatient;
input PID adm_dt_op dis_dt_op hsp_id_op @@;
cards;
1 01/05/2013 01/05/2013 10000
2 01/06/2013 01/06/2013 10111
4 01/19/2013 01/19/2013 10001
;;

data want;

PID  adm_dt     dis_dt     hsp_id adm_dt_op dis_dt_op   hs_id_op OP
1    01/01/2013 01/03/2013 10001  01/05/2013 01/05/2013 10000    Yes
2    01/03/2013 01/04/2013 10110  01/06/2013 01/06/2013 10111    Yes
3    01/10/2012 01/12/2012 10010  .          .           .       No
4    01/11/2013 01/17/2013 10000  01/19/2013 01/19/2013 10001    Yes`
```

Answer (score 3):

Lots of solutions to this pretty basic problem.  Merge the two datasets:

```
data want;
merge inpatient(in=i) outpatient(in=o keep=PID);
if i;
if o then Outpatient='Yes';
else outpatient='No';
run;
```

Works even if you have multiple variables to merge on, does require a sort so can be slow for very large datasets.

Create a format:

```
data op_format;
start=pid;
label='Yes';
fmtname='Outpf';
output;
if _n_ = 1 then do;  *add a row that instructs it what to do with nonmatching records;
hlo='o';
label='No';
output;
end;
run;

proc format cntlin=op_format;
quit;

data want;
set inpatient;
outpatient=put(pid,outpf.);
run;
```

Only works with one merge variable (without silly tricks like catting values together).

If these two don't work for you, there are other solutions - SQL, hash table, etc., depending on your data, your familiarity with various things, etc.

SQL solution, roughly:

```
proc sql;
create table want as
  select I.*, case when missing(O.PID) then 'No' else 'Yes' end as OP
  from inpatient I left join outpatient O
  on I.pid=O.pid;
quit;
```

Comment: Thanks and it looks like your merge option will work in this case but due to large dataset sorting may take me some time. Is it possible to do something like this in PROC SQL?

Comment: SQL still has to do the sort in some fashion, it's not like it can just magically combine records :)  It's possible it might do it faster using a hash table, but I don't know that it would if PID is fairly unique.

Answer (score 1):

This should be helpful. Sorry I switched to R about a year ago and dont have SAS on my pc anymore to test.

```
    PROC SQL; 
     CREATE TABLE Patient_Matches AS 
     SELECT *
     FROM inpatient left join outpatient
     ON inpatient.PID = outpatient.PID 
     ; 
     QUIT;


     PROC SQL;
       ALTER TABLE Patient_Matches ADD OPchar(2);
       UPDATE Patient_MatchesSET myString='NO' where hs_id_op  = '';
       UPDATE Patient_MatchesSET myString='YES' where hs_id_op  <> '';
     quit;
```

Comment: I am trying to compare PID between two datasets and then label OP variable as Yes or No.

Comment: That's way overkill for this.  He doesn't need * from outpatient, after all, and you can do all of the yes/no stuff in the select using CASE.

Comment: Thats definitely true. I always assume when people post on there they need the solution quickly and I dont have SAS on my machine anymore to putz with.